# Form appending values to URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a form that is submitted by JQuery. Sometimes when the form submission fails, the values inside the form are automagically appended as query string to the url. I have searched a lot but am not able to find anything on this strange behaviour. Here is an example of what happens.

There is a form with two fields

```js
$("#MyForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "UserName": {
                required: true
            },
            "Password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "UserName": {
                required: "UserName is required"
            },
            "Password": {
                required: "Password is required"
            }
        },


        submitHandler: function () {
         var userName = $("#UserName").val();
         var password = $("#Password").val();
         var myObject = {UserName:userName, Password: password}  
          $.post('/MyAuthenticationUrl',myObject,function(){
            //Redirect to Home page on success
          });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="/MyUrl"/>
  <input type="text" id="UserName" />
  <input type="password" id="Password"/>
  <input type="submit" id="Submit"/>
<form>
```

For form validation and submission, I use the JqueryValidation plugin from the [JqueryValidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Sometimes when I click on submit, the userName and password get appended to the querystring.

So if you have a url like http://localhost/Home/Index it becomes
http://localhost/Home/Index/?UserName=blah&Password=blah

I suspect it has to do something with the JqueryValidation plugin but I haven't been able to find anything related in the issues page [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues)

Comment: Try adding `method="post"` to your form tag.

Comment: You should check console when it fails, i guess you should get error message there

Comment: @GentlemanMax But the plugin prevent default behaviour of form submit, using ajax method, if i'm correct

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes.  But when the plugin is failing the form is submitting normally.  Why the plugin is failing is likely a separate issue.

Comment: @GentlemanMax If by plugin failing you mean there is any error in OP's code, then ya. I think OP should ask question regarding why his plugin is failing then

Comment: @A.Wolff, I was just pointing out what was causing the "weird" behavior. As for why the plugin is failing, I agree with you that the OP should check the console for the JS error.

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with plugin directly and there is a javascript error being thrown which would be seen in browser console

Comment: The code snippet is not going to work properly if you don't include the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently don't have the jQuery Validate plugin properly included and initialized (not in your OP), so you're simply submitting the form to the URL in the `action` attribute.

The reported issue describes the default behavior of a (non-ajax) form submit when you don't have the `method="post"` attribute within the `form` tag... a query string is appended to the URL by default.

This has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.

---

As far as this goes...

```
submitHandler: function () {
    var userName = $("#UserName").val();
    var password = $("#Password").val();
    var myObject = {UserName:userName, Password: password}  
    $.post('/MyAuthenticationUrl',myObject,function(){
        //Redirect to Home page on success
    });
}
```

The `submitHandler` is not coming into play since the plugin is broken (not included, JavaScript error, etc.).  However, your intention seems to be to use ajax `.post()` to submit the form and `"Redirect to Home page on success"`.  I don't understand the point of this.  If you want to redirect to another URL, then you don't need ajax... simply employ the URL of the `action` attribute and the form will submit and redirect to this URL automatically.  Taking out the `submitHandler` entirely will revert to this default behavior.

Your markup...

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" />
<input type="password" id="Password"/>
```

To use the jQuery Validate plugin, you **MUST** have a `name` attribute on any field considered for validation.

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" />
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"/>
```

There is no exception or workaround for this; it's how the plugin internally keeps track of the various elements.

---

Finally, you have your question tagged with [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).  In ASP, the jQuery Validate plugin is automatically initialized by the included Unobtrusive Validation plugin.  If that's the case then you cannot call the `.validate()` method directly since the Unobtrusive Validation plugin automatically constructs and calls `.validate()` based on the data attributes in the HTML markup.  The jQuery Validate plugin will only use the first instance of `.validate()` and totally ignore any subsequent calls.

Remove your call to `.validate()` to verify this.  If nothing changes then you'll know that either it was being over-ridden by ASP's built-in Unobtrusive Validation or that it was entirely broken in the first place.